# Using a Tensorflow input pipeline with skflow/tf learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, skflow

I've followed the Tensorflow [Reading Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/reading_data/index.html) guide to get my app's data in the form of TFRecords, and am using TFRecordReader in my input pipelines to read this data.

I'm now reading the guides on using [skflow/tf.learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn) to build a simple regressor, but I can't see how to use my input data with these tools.

In the following code, the app fails on the `regressor.fit(..)` call, with `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tf.py", line 138, in <module>
    run()
  File ".../tf.py", line 86, in run
    regressor.fit(x, labels)
  File ".../site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/base.py", line 218, in fit
    self.batch_size)
  File ".../site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 99, in setup_train_data_feeder
    return data_feeder_cls(X, y, n_classes, batch_size)
  File ".../site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.X = check_array(X, dtype=x_dtype)
  File ".../site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/data_feeder.py", line 161, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=None, copy=False)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn

def inputs():
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])

        reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

        features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_spec)
        labels = features.pop('actual')
        some_feature = features['some_feature']

        features_batch, labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [some_feature, labels], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
            min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

        return features_batch, labels_batch


def run():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        x, labels = inputs()

        # regressor = learn.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(hidden_units=[10, 20, 10])
        regressor = learn.TensorFlowLinearRegressor()

        regressor.fit(x, labels)
        ...
```

It looks like the `check_array` call is expecting a real array, not a tensor. Is there anything I can do to massage my data into the right shape?

Comment: What happens if you do x = x.eval() and labels = labels.eval() before your regressor.fit call? This should evaluate the tensor into an array, but I doubt this is the correct way of doing this with skflow...

Comment: @mathetes, that seems to work but before I head down this path, is that the 'tf-y' way of doing things? My intuition is that the TF graph should be moving the data around, not my program.

Comment: Absolutely, I'm sorry I didn't specify but it was meant just as a way of debugging. That's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. I can't help you further though, I'm not familiar with skflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API that you were working with is depreciated. If you use a more modern [`tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearRegressor) (I think >= 1.0), you are supposed to specify the [`input_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn), which basically produces the inputs and labels. I think in your example, that would be as simple as changing your `run` function to:

```
def run():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor()
        regressor.fit(input_fn=my_input_fn)
```

and then defining an input function called `my_input_fn`. From [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn), this input function takes the form:

```
def my_input_fn():

    # Preprocess your data here...

    # ...then return 1) a mapping of feature columns to Tensors with
    # the corresponding feature data, and 2) a Tensor containing labels
    return feature_cols, labels
```

I think the documentation can get you the rest of the way. It is difficult from here for me to say how you should proceed without seeing your data.

Comment: You're right that this was an old problem & I'm way past it now. Thank you for providing a useful, current solution.